# error: request for member ‘-----’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, nodes

I have these two error message when compiling with gcc

```
error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union
    else if(strcmp((*node).name, (*root).name) < 0)



error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[101]’ from type ‘char *’
    (*node).name = SomeString;
```

from what I have found the first error normally occurs when you try and call a node like this

```
node.name;
```

instead of

```
(*node).name;
```

As that is not the case here Im wondering what leads to the error and how to fix it?

the node is defined as:

```
struct person {
    char name[42];
    struct person *left, *right;
} root;
```

and created by

```
struct person *node;
node = (struct person *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct person));
(*node).name = SomeString;
```

Comment: Note that it is more typical to use node->name instead of (*node).name

Comment: `root` is not a pointer. It's an object. Use `root.name` instead of `(*root).name`.

Comment: @RSahu How do you know `root` is not a pointer?

Comment: @Daniel, the posted code defines `root` to be an object.

Comment: @RSahu Ah. I missed that.

Comment: please post a minimal complete example rather than snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have no the assignment operator. You have to use standard function `strcpy` declared in header `<string.h>` for characters arrays when you want to assign a string to a character array

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( (*node).name, SomeString; );
```

As for the first error then `root` is not a pointer. You have to write

```
else if(strcmp((*node).name, root.name) < 0)
```

instead of

```
else if(strcmp((*node).name, (*root).name) < 0)
```

I think that it would be more correctly to define `root` as

```
struct person {
    char name[42];
    struct person *left, *right;
} *root = NULL;
```

Comment: @user2856110  See my updated post. I did not understand at first that the first error you did not update.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
node->name
```

Since node is a pointer you have to access structure members as shown above.

Also strcpy() should be used to assign value to your structure member.

```
strcpy(node->name,"hello");

struct person *root;
```

will solve your first error

Comment: tried that earlier, same result. ( (*node).name and node->name are the same as far as I have understood, merely a matter of taste)

Comment: Yes (*node).name can also be used but not node.name as shown in your code

Comment: @user2856110 It's not really a matter of taste. Functionally (*node).name and node->name do the same thing, but in general, C programmers prefer the -> notation because it is easier to read.

Comment: @Daniel In the question asked OP uses node.name so I said that is wrong

Answer (score 0):

It is more preferable and mostly adapted to use '->' (arrow operator) to access the structure member when we are using a pointer variable to access it.
so instead of
`(*node).name`
we can use
`node->name`

For more information on strings in C you can visit this wiki link, which will be really helpful:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling